# how does physical disk read work with volume shadow for ntfs?

Tags: winapi, ntfs, volume-shadow-service

my goal is to make a backup program reading a physical disk (with NTFS partitions) while using VSS for data consistency.

i use windows api's functions CreateFile with '\.\PhysicalDriveN'
as described here (basically, it allow me to access a disk as a big file)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/100027/info-direct-drive-access-under-win32

for tests i create volume shadows with this command

```
wmic shadowcopy call create Volume='C:\'
```

this is a temporary solution, i plan on using VSS via the program itself

**My question is:**
how are stored Volume shadows? does it stores data that have been modified since the volume shadow or does it store modification made since the last volume shadow?

**in the first case:**
    when i read the disk, will i get consistent data (including ntfs metadata files)?

**in the other case:**
    can i access a volume shadow the same way i would access a disk/partition? (in order to read hidden metadata files, etc)

-im am currenctly using windows 7 but planning on using it on differents version of windows server

-i've read a lot of microsoft doc about VSS but how it work seem really unclear for me (if you answer with one please explain a bit it meaning)

-i know that Volume shadows are stored in the folder "System Volume Information" as files with names like {3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did more test and actually Shadow Volume are made at block level not file level. it mean that by using createfile with the path 
`\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1` it would work in a similar way than using createfile with the path `\\.\C:`

So yeah you can access a shadow copy file system, it have it own boot sector, mft, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"*how are stored Volume shadows? does it stores data that have been modified since the volume shadow or does it store modification made since the last volume shadow?*"

A hardware or software shadow copy provider uses one of the following methods for creating a shadow copy:(Answer by [msdn doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service))

> **Complete copy** This method makes a complete copy (called a "full copy"
>   or "clone") of the original volume at a given point in time. This copy
>   is read-only.
>
> **Copy-on-write** This method does not copy the original volume. Instead,
>   it makes a differential copy by copying all changes (completed write
>   I/O requests) that are made to the volume after a given point in time.
>
> **Redirect-on-write** This method does not copy the original volume, and
>   it does not make any changes to the original volume after a given
>   point in time. Instead, it makes a differential copy by redirecting
>   all changes to a different volume.

"*when i read the disk, will i get consistent data (including ntfs metadata files)?*"

Even if an application does not have its files open in exclusive mode, it is possible—because of the finite time needed to open, back up, and close a file—that files copied to storage media may not all reflect the same application state.

"*can i access a volume shadow the same way i would access a disk/partition? (in order to read hidden metadata files, etc)*"

[Requester Access to Shadow Copied Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/vss/requestor-access-to-shadow-copied-data)

> Paths on the shadow copied volume are obtained by replacing the root
>   of the original path with the device object. For example, given a path
>   on the original volume of "C:\DATABASE*.mdb" and a VSS_SNAPSHOT_PROP
>   instance of snapProp, you would obtain the path on the shadow copied
>   volume by concatenating snapProp.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject, "\",
>   and "\DATABASE*.mdb".

Comment: thanks for the answer, 
there is just 2 point i would like to clarify:
-i use default windows VSS (wich is a volume shadow provider? tell me if i'm wrong) is it copy on write or redirect on write?

-i should have mentionned i am aware about how to access the shadow copied data, my question what about if i would be able to read it as a ntfs partition or in a different way (should i edit my question? im new to all this)

Comment: 1. copy on write. 2. I think this question may help you, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910457/copy-files-from-vss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910457/copy-files-from-vss)

Comment: thanks, but my problem is more specific, i am aware of how to acces the shadow volume, my problem is that i would like to read this shadow volume as a NTFS partition (i have my own custom driver for that). -> will the content of the shadow volume be ntfs partition like or act in another way. thanks for your patience.